# R using get() inside colnames

Tags: r, get

i have a general item string:

```
item='shoes'
```

then i use:

```
assign(paste0(item,'_list'),lapply(etc))

assign(paste0(item,'_df'),sapply(etc))
```

then i want to change the colnames of the data-frame
with the names inside a character vector:

```
v=c('a','b','c')
```

i try to do:

```
colnames(get(paste0(item,'_df'))=v
```

bu i have the:

```
could not find function "get<-"
```

error

Comment: I think something like `eval(parse(paste0("colnames(",item,"_df) <- v"))`, but as usual if you find yourself using `eval(parse(...))` you should probably reconsider your strategy, i.e. keep your individual items within a named list ...

Comment: thanks i never used the eval(parse()) functions

Answer (score 2):

I would create the names in the object being `assign()`-ed. Not sure about chances of success with the second assignment, since I generally expect `sapply` to return a matrix rather than a dataframe, which seems to be your expectation:

```
assign(paste0(item,'_list'), setNames(lapply(etc), v))

assign(paste0(item,'_df'), setNames(sapply(etc), v))
```

The `names` function will work with lists, dataframes and vectors, but I think it's not particularly well matched with matrices. It doesn't throw an error (as I expected it would) but rather creates a `names` attribute on a matrix that looks very out of place. In particular it does not set either rownames or colnames for a matrix. If you wanted something that did assign column names to a matrix this might succeed:

```
setColNames <- function (object = nm, nm) 
{ if ( class(object) %in% c("list", "data.frame", "numeric", "character") ){
    names(object) <- nm
    return(object) 
   } else{
  if ( class(object) %in% c("matrix") ){
    colnames(object) <- nm
    return(object)
  } else { object }
                         }
}
```

Comment: i will try this solution;did not knew the setNames()function.